# Low Search / Channel Entries Search running very slow in EE2 after move to MySQL 5.7

Tags: channel-entries, low-search, mysql

I've got an old website that's running EE 2.11.2 and Low Search 4.4.4.

I'm trying to move the site from a cPanel VPS that runs MySQL 5.6, to a new cPanel VPS (with more RAM so it should be faster) that runs MySQL 5.7.

Everything is setup the same on each of the VPS's, and this is using PHP 5.4. I've been testing the site and noticed that everything seems okay, except that performing a search with a Low Search form is taking about 7 seconds on this new VPS, but it was only taking about 1 second on the old VPS.

The only difference I can see is that this new VPS is using MySQL 5.7 instead of 5.6.

Looking at the template debugging, it seems to slow down a lot after the 'Low Search: Calling the channel module' line. If I disable whatever extensions are listed after that, it doesn't really make any difference and whatever follows 'Low Search: Calling the channel module' is taking over 3 seconds (which is a large chunk of this extra time).

(0.221607 / 23.93MB) Low Search: Pre-applying search vars to tagdata 
(0.231355 / 24.14MB) Low Search: Calling the channel module 
(3.521634 / 26.05MB) Calling Extension Class/Method: Low_reorder_ext/channel_entries_query_result

I asked this question to Low on his support forums but he replied with this:

> It might look like a LS issue, but the time gap between those to log
>   entries is practically all native workings. Low Search uses the native
>   Channel Entries tag to generate the search results. When LS says
>   'Calling the channel module', it has done most of the work, set the
>   fixed_order or entry_id parameters, and calls channel:entries to let
>   it parse the entries. That's where it takes a lot of time, but LS is
>   pretty much done by then (apart from some minor post-processing). So,
>   not a lot LS can do here.

Does anyone have any idea why using Low Search might seem to work a lot slower in MySQL 5.7 and if there's any fixes for this? Thanks.

Comment: Hello Stephen did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi Paul, sorry, only just seen this. No, we never resolved the issue I'm afraid. Our workaround was to manually downgrade MySQL from 5.7 to 5.6, which isn't great. Have you had any more luck with this?